# How to check "instanceof " class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

In Kotlin class, I have method parameter as object (See Kotlin doc [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) ) for class type **T**. As object I am passing different classes when I am calling method.
In Java we can able to compare class using `instanceof` of object which class it is.

So I want to check and compare at runtime which Class it is?

How can I check `instanceof` class in Kotlin?

Answer (score 466, accepted):

Use `is`.

```
if (myInstance is String) { ... }
```

or the reverse `!is`

```
if (myInstance !is String) { ... }
```

Comment: This only works when the instance object is created from a Kotlin class. This will not work if the instance was created using newInstance() from something like SomeClass::class.java

Comment: @androiddev why is that?

Comment: No idea. I tried it but it doesn't work. Some quirk with the way Kotlin interacts with Java. However, you can use SomeClass.isInstance(someObject), which does work.

Answer (score 72):

Combining `when` and `is`:

```
when (x) {
    is Int -> print(x + 1)
    is String -> print(x.length + 1)
    is IntArray -> print(x.sum())
}
```

copied from [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html)

Comment: Yes this is the idiomatic way.

Answer (score 35):

We can check whether an object conforms to a given type at runtime by using the `is` operator or its negated form `!is`.

**Example:**

```
if (obj is String) {
    print(obj.length)
}

if (obj !is String) {
    print("Not a String")
}
```

**Another Example in case of Custom Object:**

Let, I have an `obj` of type `CustomObject`.

```
if (obj is CustomObject) {
    print("obj is of type CustomObject")
}

if (obj !is CustomObject) {
    print("obj is not of type CustomObject")
}
```

Comment: Note one other nice thing here: inside the block of the `if`, `obj` is automatically cast to `String`. So you can use properties such as `length` directly, without the need to explicitly cast `obj` to `String` inside the block.

Comment: Also, nice opportunity to use an else statement ;)

Comment: What if i want to differentiate two classes where one extends the other e.g LinearLayoutManager & GridLayoutManager

Answer (score 10):

Try using keyword called `is`
[Official page reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html)

```
if (obj is String) {
    // obj is a String
}
if (obj !is String) {
    // // obj is not a String
}
```

Comment: It is great thing to give answer with official doc. But it is better practices to add sample code in answer, it is helpful if link was dead. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `is`:

```
class B
val a: A = A()
if (a is A) { /* do something */ }
when (a) {
  someValue -> { /* do something */ }
  is B -> { /* do something */ }
  else -> { /* do something */ }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can check like this

```
 private var mActivity : Activity? = null
```

then

```
 override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)

    if (context is MainActivity){
        mActivity = context
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can read Kotlin Documentation here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html . We can check whether an object conforms to a given type at runtime by using the `is` operator or its negated form `!is`, for the example using `is`:

```
fun <T> getResult(args: T): Int {
    if (args is String){ //check if argumen is String
        return args.toString().length
    }else if (args is Int){ //check if argumen is int
        return args.hashCode().times(5)
    }
    return 0
}
```

then in main function i try to print and show it on terminal :

```
fun main() {
    val stringResult = getResult("Kotlin")
    val intResult = getResult(100)

    // TODO 2
    println(stringResult)
    println(intResult)
}
```

This is the output

```
6
500
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a collection of objects, you can also keep those that are specific instance:

```kotlin
interface Fruit
class Peach: Fruit
class Watermelon: Fruit

val fruits = listOf(
    Peach(),
    Peach(),
    Watermelon(),
    Peach(),
    Watermelon()
)

val peaches = fruits.filterIsInstance(Peach::class.java)
```

Answer (score -8):

Other solution : **KOTLIN**

```
val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)

if (fragment?.tag == "MyFragment")
{}
```