# How to identify authentification error type in AWS Amplify using Kotlin?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, kotlin, aws-amplify

I want to display different errors to the user when they are logging in through AWS Amplify using Kotlin. This is what I have set up as my last parameter of `Amplify.Auth.signIn()`:

```
{ error ->
     inputEmail.error = "Check if the e-mail is valid"
     inputPassword.error = "Check if the password is valid"
})
```

"error" is a "Throwable?" which I wanted to cast to various AWS exceptions and check whether the cast was a success. Yet all of the AWS Amplify exceptions are based on the Java version of "Throwable". Is there a way to make these casts work or is there an alternative way to identify error types in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last argument in [the `signIn(...)`](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/blob/main/core/src/main/java/com/amplifyframework/auth/AuthCategoryBehavior.java#L97-L108) method is of type `Consumer<AuthException>`. This is a function that accepts an `AuthException`, and does something with it. So, you shouldn't need to [downcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting) the input.

There are [a few types exception that extend `AuthException`](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/search?q=%22extends+AuthException%22).

As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48213377/695787), I suggest is to exhaust those types using a `when` construct. Paraphrasing:

```kotlin
when (error) {
    is SessionUnavailableOfflineException -> doSomething()
    is InvalidAccountTypeException -> doSomethingElse()
    // etc.
}
```

You can also check for errors in the active auth session with [`fetchAuthSession(...)`](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/access_credentials/q/platform/android):

```kotlin
Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession(
    { result ->
        val cognitoAuthSession = result as AWSCognitoAuthSession
        if (AuthSessionResult.Type.FAILURE == cognitoAuthSession.identityId.type) {
            // do stuff
        }
    },
    { error -> Log.e("AuthQuickStart", error.toString()) }
)
```

Comment: This is a more elegant way of checking its type, yes, thank You. But let's say I want to check for "UserNotConfirmedException" about which I am informed only in the message but "error" is uncastable to it. Would Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession() work to check for such error?

Comment: Hey @KapitaiN - you're right that currently we don't categorize errors like the ones you're looking to identify such as UserNotConfirmed, username does not exist, or wrong password. This is a gap we're aware of and have in our backlog to address.

Comment: @DavidDaudelin Alright, thanks for the help! I'll think of something then.