# Generic initialization of KCache

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have a problem making the initialization of a [KCache](https://github.com/rayokota/kcache) cache generic. The code is as follows:

```
class MyCache(name: String, test: Boolean = true) {
    private val cache: SortedMap<String, MyAvroObject>
    init {
        if (test) {
            cache = sortedMapOf()
        }
        else {
            val cacheProps = Properties()
            cacheProps[KafkaCacheConfig.KAFKACACHE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] =
                appConfig.propertyOrNull("kafka.bootstrapServers")?.getString()
            cacheProps[KafkaCacheConfig.KAFKACACHE_GROUP_ID_CONFIG] =
                appConfig.propertyOrNull("applicationId")?.getString()
            cacheProps[KafkaCacheConfig.KAFKACACHE_CLIENT_ID_CONFIG] = "GeneratingUnitsCache"
            cacheProps[KafkaCacheConfig.KAFKACACHE_TOPIC_CONFIG] = "app.$name.kcache"
            val serdeConfig = Collections.singletonMap(
                AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG,
                appConfig.property("kafka.schemaRegistryUrl").getString(),
            )
            //*** WISH TO MAKE THIS PART GENERIC
            val avroSerdes: Serde<MyAvroObject> = SpecificAvroSerde()
            avroSerdes.configure(serdeConfig, false)
            cache = KafkaCache(
                KafkaCacheConfig(cacheProps),
                Serdes.String(),
                avroSerdes
            )
            cache.init()
            //***
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on which topic you consume from, the cache will contain different objects. For example, the cache could contain `MyAvroObject`, `String` or `MyAvroObject2`. The problem then becomes to initialize the cache with the correct Serdes (serializer / deserializer) depending on what kind of objects the cache will contain.

I have tried to make the actual definition of the cache generic:

```
class MyCache<T>(name: String, test: Boolean = true){
    private val cache: SortedMap<String, T>
...
```

but then I struggle to get the type of T when I have to choose the right Serdes. Are there any Kotlin wizards out there who know if it is possible to make the initialization generic?

Comment: "get the type of T"... That defeats the point of generics. If you're using Avro, you should just use GenericRecord

Comment: Say that I also wanted to handle `String` objects?  The whole class is made generic, except for the initialization of the `KafkaCache`. The choice of the value `Serdes` object is to my understanding dependent on the type of `T`. For instance, if `T` is a string then `Serdes.string()` should be used. Essentially my problem is to initialize the cache correctly.

Comment: Your class definition seems correct (although I don't know Kotlin), but sounds like you want [`is` or `when`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48213377/2308683) to get a Serde object. Or perhaps [`Class.isAssignableFrom`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4704933/2308683)